# Syntax error when Installing NetBSD pkgsrc on RHEL 4

Tags: gcc, rhel, netbsd, pkgsrc

I'm trying to install NETBSD pkgsrc in unprivileged mode on RHEL4 with GCC 3.4.6. First of all is this setup too old?

I downloaded the latest stable release from http://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/pkgsrc/stable/pkgsrc.tar.gz.

When running the bootstrap script using the following command I'm getting a syntax error:

```
./bootstrap --unprivileged --prefix /the_directory_im_using/pkgtest --varbase /the_directory_im_using/var

/bootstrap/work/wrk/pkgtools/pkg_install/work/libarchive/libarchive -I/the_directory_im_using/pkgsrc/bootstrap/work/wrk/pkgtools/pkg_install/work/libfetch -DHAVE_NBCOMPAT_H=1 -I/the_directory_im_using/pkgsrc/bootstrap/work/wrk/pkgtools/pkg_install/work/libnbcompat -I/usr/include -I. -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGE_FILES -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DINET6 -DWITH_SSL -DFTP_COMBINE_CWDS -c ftp.c
In file included from /the_directory_im_using/pkgsrc/bootstrap/work/wrk/pkgtools/pkg_install/work/libnbcompat/nbcompat.h:50,
             from ftp.c:69:
    /the_directory_im_using/pkgsrc/bootstrap/work/wrk/pkgtools/pkg_install/work/libnbcompat/nbcompat/ctype.h:44: error: syntax error before ')' token
*** Error code 1
```

The line that's causing the problem is:

```
#if !HAVE_DECL_ISBLANK
int     isblank(int);
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the define that's causing the problem to:

```
#ifndef HAVE_DECL_ISBLANK
int     isblank(int); 
#endif
```

And it seems to have finished correctly, though I'm having other problems now.